# Does Magento know the date that an item went out of stock?

Tags: magento-1.9, rss

In order for my RSS feed to inform me of low inventory changes I need to know the date that the item became low in inventory. If I do not have this date then every time I refresh the feed in a browser or reader it looks at the pubDate - which changes every rss load - and thinks that all of the items have updated.

Comment: You could create an Observer that updates a log file every time a product goes out of stock or hits a certain stock level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may be in luck. The `cataloginventory_stock_item` table has a column for `low_stock_date` with a timestamp as its value. You'll need to update the RSS feed to pull from that column of that table for each product, but it does look like the data exists in Magento.

This is a database design of Magento CE 1.7.0.2, but it was the best resource I could find and should still be accurate enough for this purpose. http://www.magereverse.com/index/magento-database-diagram/version/1-7-0-2

Comment: Thanks, using the information you provided I was able to add the lastUpdate key to the data array in NotifyStock.php. Now, rather than showing all out of stock product as new in my feed reader per refresh the feed only updates when the lastUpdate field has been modified.

`
  $data = array(
            'title'         => $product->getName(),
            'link'          => $url,
            'description'   => $description,
    /* Continue Tyler's Mod */
   'lastUpdate' => strtotime($lowInventoryDate),
        );
`